# How to retrieve test with highest WPM and accuracy, without failing if a test with higher WPM exists?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, querying

I'm trying to retrieve the test from a user that has the highest `WPM` and `accuracy` with a time of `60 seconds`. I've managed to get the test with the highest WPM and accuracy. If there are two tests with the same wpm and accuracy then the `createdAt` date is used to pick a test, so the test with the older createdAt date is picked. The problem is that if there are two tests with the same WPM and accuracy, and there's a third test with a higher WPM, the query fails to return any test.

Here is the query builder:

```
const qb = ctx.em
      .createQueryBuilder(Test, 'test')
      .innerJoin(
        (subQuery) =>
          subQuery
            .select('MAX(t.wpm)', 'max_wpm')
            .addSelect('t.creatorId', 'creatorId')
            .addSelect('MAX(t.accuracy)', 'max_accuracy')
            .from(Test, 't')
            .where('t.time = :time', { time: '60' })
            .groupBy('t.creatorId'),
        'max_tests',
        'max_tests.max_wpm = test.wpm AND max_tests."creatorId" = test."creatorId" AND max_tests.max_accuracy = test.accuracy'
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect('test.creator', 'creator')
      .where('test.time = :time', { time: '60' })
      .andWhere((qb) => {
        const subQuery = qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('MIN(t2.createdAt)')
          .from(Test, 't2')
          .where('t2.creatorId = test.creatorId')
          .andWhere('t2.wpm = test.wpm')
          .andWhere('t2.accuracy = test.accuracy')
          .getQuery();
        return `test."createdAt" = (${subQuery})`;
      })
      .orderBy('test.wpm', 'DESC')
      .addOrderBy('test.accuracy', 'DESC')
```

And here are three example tests:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "wpm": 96,
    "accuracy": 96.7,
    "time": "60",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-09T11:26:42.003917Z",
    "creatorId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "wpm": 96,
    "accuracy": 96.7,
    "time": "60",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-09T12:58:48.956275Z",
    "creatorId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "wpm": 97,
    "accuracy": 97,
    "time": "60",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-09T13:18:21.991219Z",
    "creatorId": 1
  }
]
```

The expected result is to get test #3, but my current code fails to return anything.

How can I modify my query?

Database: postgreSQL
orm: typeorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was that I was comparing both wpm and accuracy at the same time, so if two tests have the same wpm and accuracy and if the third test has a higher wpm but lower accuracy then the query fails which was what happened in this case. So I modified the queryBuilder to first check for highest wpm and if there's two tests with the same wpm then check for accuracy and if there is a duplication then check for createdAt date.

Here is the final qb:

```
const qb = ctx.em
      .createQueryBuilder(Test, 'test')
      .innerJoin(
        (subQuery) =>
          subQuery
            .select('MAX(t.wpm)', 'max_wpm')
            .addSelect('t.creatorId', 'creatorId')
            .from(Test, 't')
            .where('t.time = :time', { time: '60' })
            .groupBy('t.creatorId'),
        'max_tests',
        'max_tests.max_wpm = test.wpm AND max_tests."creatorId" = test."creatorId"'
      )
      .where('test.time = :time', { time: '60' })
      .andWhere((qb) => {
        const subQuery = qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('MAX(t2.accuracy)')
          .from(Test, 't2')
          .where('t2.time = :time')
          .andWhere('t2.wpm = test.wpm')
          .andWhere('t2.creatorId = test.creatorId')
          .setParameter('time', '60')
          .getQuery();
        return `test.accuracy = (${subQuery})`;
      })
      .andWhere((qb) => {
        const subQuery = qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('MIN(t3.createdAt)')
          .from(Test, 't3')
          .where('t3.creatorId = test.creatorId')
          .andWhere('t3.wpm = test.wpm')
          .andWhere('t3.accuracy = test.accuracy')
          .setParameter('time', '60')
          .getQuery();
        return `test."createdAt" = (${subQuery})`;
      })
      .leftJoinAndSelect('test.creator', 'creator')
      .orderBy('test.wpm', 'DESC')
      .addOrderBy('test.accuracy', 'DESC')
      .addOrderBy('test.createdAt', 'ASC');
```